# C increment/decrement operators

Tags: c

Determine the value of each variable after calculation is performed. All variables have  value 5 before execution.

1. `A1/=++B1/--C1`
2. `A2+=++B2%C2--`

please tell me how this work

Comment: Write a program to print the answer?, Lookup operator precedence rules? Do your own homework?

Comment: This isn't domyhomeworkforme.com.

Comment: i wanna know how it is been executed..the steps how this operators work.. i have more similar questions. i want to know the pattern for this. also i got the answer as (a). 5 and (b) 6. i want to know how did that come.. because when i do it by my self it comes as 3.3333 therefor 3(integer).

Answer (score 2):

Variables:

```
int A1 = 5;
int B1 = 5;
int C1 = 5;

int A2 = 5;
int B2 = 5;
int C2 = 5;
```

Your code:

```
A1 /= ++B1 / --C1;
A2 += ++B2 % C2--;
```

Will probably compile into something similar too:

```
++B1;
--C1;
A1 /= B1 / C1;

++B2;
A2 += B2 % C2;
C2--;
```

You can output the ASM using your compiler, with GCC its the -S flag. Here is the ASM output with GCC on my computer (I added the comments):

```
movl    $5, -20(%rbp) // A1 = 5
movl    $5, -24(%rbp) // B1 = 5
movl    $5, -28(%rbp) // C1 = 5
movl    $5, -32(%rbp) // A2 = 5
movl    $5, -36(%rbp) // B2 = 5
movl    $5, -40(%rbp) // C2 = 5
```

Then for the first one calculation, this is performed (comments simplified for easier understanding):

```
addl    $1, -24(%rbp)      // ++B1
subl    $1, -28(%rbp)      // --C1
movl    -24(%rbp), %eax    // 
cltd
idivl   -28(%rbp)          // divide B1 by C1
movl    %eax, %esi         // 
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax    // 
cltd
idivl   %esi               // divide A1 by the previous
movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)
```

Comment: Although, C2-- will probably be compiled out by a smart compiler.

Comment: i got my answer as 5 for (a) part when i compiled. but when i do it anualy i get 3. is it possible?

Comment: I get 5 and 6, don't forget integer division doesn't store the decimal.

Comment: yes i also got it. thank you Scott.

Answer (score 0):

By the C Operator Precedence Table: http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

**For 1:**

```
A1 /= ++B1 / --C1
```

- C1 will first be decremented by 1 to 4
- B1 will then be incremented by 1 to 6
- B1 (6) will be divided by C1 (4), result of which will be 1
- A1 will be assigned with the result of the division A1 (5) and 1, which is 5

Results for each will be 5, 6 and 4 for A1, B1 and C1, respectively.

**For 2:**

```
A2 += ++B2 % C2--
```

- C2 will first be marked to get decremented close to the end of the statement, remains 5 for now
- B2 will then be incremented by 1 to 6
- The remainder from the division B2 (6) by C2 (5) will get calculated, which is 1
- A2 will be assigned with the result of the addition of A2 (5) and 1, which is 6
- C2 will be decremented by 1 to 4

Results for each will be 6, 6 and 4 for A2, B2 and C2, respectively.

Pardon me if I have made any mistakes, you can always check these with your compiler.

Comment: its correct.. thank you so much ThoAppelsin.

Comment: @user3299725 np bro, unisex bro, applies regardless of your gender. *bro* truly should be unisex... Whatever, glad it's correct and that I helped